# Implementing Transactions in an ORM-system

Tags: java, sql, orm, transactions, innodb

I am building a Java application, and I'm also building an ORM (Object-relational mapping), which provides DAO's (Data Access Object's). Maybe it was smarter to use one of the existing ones, but I am having pretty much fun in trying to design the ORM.

Currently it exists very basic out of these classes cq functions:

- Beans (Data is stored in these objects)
- Constraints (These tie together with the beans and are used for searching)
- Managers (On these objects you will insert/update/delete/search data)

Now I want to add an extra layer, namely Transitions. I think they fall somewhere between the Managers and the actual PreparedStatement that are being used. I know I could use the SQL connection directly, but that doesn't seem so nice and object-orientated to me.

Most important layout is the one of the Manager class:

```
public abstract class Manager<B extends Bean, C extends AbstractConstraint<B>> {
    protected final Connection connection;

    public Manager(final Connection con) {
        this.connection = con;
    }

    public final int insert(B b) throws InsertException {

    }

    public final boolean update(B b) throws UpdateException {

    }

    public final boolean delete(B b) throws DeleteException {

    }

    public final B get(C... c) throws SearchException {

    }

    public final List<B> search(C... c) throws SearchException {

    }

    public final List<B> getAll() throws SearchException {

    }

    abstract protected PreparedStatement insertPS(B b) throws SQLException;

    abstract protected PreparedStatement updatePS(B b) throws SQLException;

    abstract protected PreparedStatement deletePS(B b) throws SQLException;

    abstract protected String searchQuery();

    abstract protected B createBean(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException;
}
```

Now I plan on adding a Transaction class, with as premise that when you enter two insert/update/delete 'statements' in there, that they will be committed as a transaction to the database.

How would I get it to work? (The given example isn't a real life example, just making up something simple)

```
Transaction transaction = new Transaction(SQL.getConnection());
//Normal execution
int insertedId = ManagerFactory.getAccountManager().insert(new Account(...));
boolean updateSucceeded = ManagerFactory.getGeneralManager().update(new General(...)); //with modified data to reflect insertion of an account
transaction.commit();
```

I was thinking about letting the `Transaction` call functions of the `Manager` directly like this:

```
Transaction transaction = new Transaction(SQL.getConnection());
transaction.add(ManagerFactory.getAccountManager(), Action.INSERT, new Account(...));
transaction.add(ManagerFactory.getGeneralManager(), Action.UPDATE, new General(...));
transaction.commit();
```

Where you have something like:

```
public void add(Manager m, Action a, Bean b) { }
```

which calls the respective action that need to be taken

How can I still return the return values to the caller?

And even if I would split it up in `addInsert()`, `addUpdate()` and `addDelete()`, how would I delay returning their return values until the `commit()` has taken place? Because only then the values will be known.

Regards.